# Using OAuth with gmail's atom feed

Tags: javascript, oauth, gmail, atom-feed

I am attempting to use OAuth to access gmail's atom feed in javascript in the browser (yes, I know the security risks of building an in-browser OAuth app; it's for personal use, and I'm not worried about me stealing my own consumer key).

However, accessing the Atom feed is giving me the wrong user.

I'm calling:

```
oa.Ajax().get("https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom?xoauth_requestor_id=user@domain.com", callback);
```

where `oa.Ajax.get` wraps the proper OAuth information (it works; I can use it to access other google services).

I've also tried calling without the `xoauth_requestor_id` parameter.

**Expected Result**:
I get the authed user's feed

**Actual Result**: I get the atom feed of the default gmail user

Anyone know why this might be happening?  Thanks.

Comment: I also tried step-by-step what the OAuth playground told me to, which didn't work (hence a bug in google's API).  I ended up just using basic access auth on `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/111111/feed/atom`, which will work as long as the user is not logged in to more than 111,111 google accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your authentication tokens, etc. using an **Authorization Header**, and I'm not sure that's possible or not using AJAX. But because you're logged into Gmail, your identity is being used to retrieve the feed and thats why you see your own feed and not that of the auth'ed user.

Comment: Your intuition is right -- you can in fact use an authorization header with AJAX, but that isn't the reason the OAuth is failing (it really is just because Gmail Atom feed doesn't adhere to the protocol).  You can, however, use basic access authentication (insecure, I know) in the authorization header to get the correct Atom feed.